# How to prevent the sides of an image from being selected

Tags: css, image, select, highlight, pointer-events

Below I have an image followed by text. How do I prevent the area surrounding it from being highlighted? The image itself is not selectable (using

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
```

) but the surrounding area of the image is. I tried adding left and right margins to the image as well as making the image its own div and applying the above code to the div, but it does not work. (I made the highlight green)

[image: See here]

**Edit**: Here is another example linked here https://jsfiddle.net/nnzf4h5c/[image: jsfiddle example]

Comment: add a snippet of your code please.

Comment: I tried with the code you provided and cannot reproduce the issue in CodePen, JSFiddle, nor StackOverflow snippets.

Comment: Hi, here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/nnzf4h5c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the content in a div with the same style:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.cont01 {
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont01"><img src="https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png">
</div>
Text
```

Comment: Thanks but this prevents the text from being highlighted now, the text is precisely what I _want_ highlighted

Comment: I have updated the answer, it seems working cross-browser.

Comment: You are welcome. You could accept the answer and/or vote it if it works.

[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)